# Why PhantomJS type only the last letter when we give an input to input field?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium WebDriver and PhantomJS as my browser and Windows7 OS.

My Code is like below.

```
public void TC_PMS_015() throws Exception{
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    homePg.clickFrontOffice();

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("main");
    FOManageReservationPg   =   homePg.clickFOManageReservation();

    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame("main");
    driver.switchTo().frame("frmTabmenu_spnTabMenus_0");
    Sleep(6);
    FOManageReservationPg.clickClearButton();
    Sleep(3);
    FOManageReservationPg.selectHotel(prop.getProperty("hotel"));
    Sleep(3);
    FOManageReservationPg.enterVoucherNumberToSearch(prop.getProperty("vouchernumber"));
    Sleep(3);
    FOManageReservationPg.clickSearchButton();
    Sleep(6);
    homePg  =   FOManageReservationPg.clickCloseButton();
    }
```

And this is the method to enter the voucher number.

```
public void enterVoucherNumberToSearch(String VoucherNo) {
        txtVoucherNo    =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtVoucherNo']"));
        uiSendKeys(txtVoucherNo, VoucherNo);
    }
```

This is the uiSendKeys Method.

```
public void uiSendKeys(WebElement uiElement,String value) {
        uiElement.clear();
        uiElement.sendKeys(value);
    }
```

When I execute this test case, "enterVoucherNumberToSearch" method only takes the last letter of the voucher.

Eg: I pass "RH0000337" as my voucher number, but it types "7" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens with the PhantomJs version.
My previous PhantomJs version was 1.9.1
I have update my version to 2.0.0
When I update my PhantomJs driver, the send keys method has taken the full text without missing any letter.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the element has not completely loaded.  I would try this:

```
public void enterVoucherNumberToSearch(String VoucherNo) {
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtVoucherNo']")));
  txtVoucherNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtVoucherNo']"));
  uiSendKeys(txtVoucherNo, VoucherNo);
}
```

**Updated**

Moving on, the next change I would try would be:

```
public void uiSendKeys(WebElement uiElement,String value) {
    uiElement.clear();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(uiElement, '');

    uiElement.sendKeys(value);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(uiElement, value);
}
```

Comment: I added the wait to the enterVoucherNumberToSearch method but it didn't fix my issue. And I print the xpath and have got the following output. Voucher nuber after setting from the xpath  -----  >  [[PhantomJSDriver: phantomjs on XP (d3630600-e681-11e5-80bf-41e6ba53f1fa)] -> xpath: //input[@id='txtVoucherNo']]

Comment: @OreliyaFernando I just noticed something.

Comment: @OreliyaFernando What is your implicit wait set to? Perhaps it needs to be set higher.  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);